# How to add storyboard reference in another storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, storyboard, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I have 2 storyboard - `mainStoryBoard1` and `mainStoryBoard2`.

I need to perform a segue from `ViewController of mainStoryBoard1` to `ViewController of mainStoryBoard2.`

Anyone has idea how to do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Interface Builder in Xcode 7 has "Storyboard Reference" object in the "Object library":

[image]

Just drag that onto your storyboard. You can then select that storyboard reference and specify the storyboard to which it refers in the attributes inspector:

[image]

Then you can now add segue to this reference and you'll segue from the scene in one storyboard to a scene in another storyboard.