# Pushing from Tabbar Storyboard to another Storyboard issue

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller, pushviewcontroller

Here are my storyBoards

[Tabbar Storyboar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8zUH.png)
[other storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNRsh.png)

here is my code to Move TabbarStoryBoard to Other Storyboard

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Tabbar", bundle: Bundle.main)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginController") as? LoginController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
```

Now when I move from Tabbar StoryBoard from Other storyboard's LoginController, and signIn with email & password and want to redirect user to Tabbar storyboard is not pushing. It is successfully pushing from Tabbar storyboard to other storyboard's view controller, even it is not pushing in same storyboard to other viewcontroller

It is not giving any error, and also not pushing to Tabbar Storyboard.
What is my issue?

**Note : Tabbar Storyboard's TabbarViewcontroller is my initial viewController**

Comment: Do you means there is another segue from the Login VC that you use to Come back to the tabbar storyboard?

Comment: How are you pushing your viewcontroller using segues in storyboard or else in code?

Comment: I am pushing viewcontroller programatically @RizwanAhmed

Comment: Can you please show us the code?

Comment: @RizwanAhmed I have updated my code

Comment: Your question is confusing... can you post clearer screen-captures, so we can see which controllers you are using? It sounds like you have a TabBar Controller, and one of the tabs contains a NavigationController, and from the root view of that Nav Controller you are pushing to your LoginController? So is your question "how to return to the root view of the nav controller"? Or "how to jump to a different tab"? Or "how to replace the nav controller in the current tab to a different controller"?

Comment: @DonMag My question is How to return to TabbarController from loginController

Comment: @JitendraModi - OK, that doesn't make sense. Your TabBarController is showing the ViewController assigned to one of the Tabs. You then **push** your `LoginController` - which means the current tab was showing the Root VC of a NavigationController. So you are ***still*** "at your TabBarController". How do you expect to "return to TabBarController" if you are already there?

Answer (score 0):

Story Board Referencing is the best thing for this... Hope these links will work.

[Use Storyboard References While Retaining Icons & Text for Tab Bar Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37241684/use-storyboard-references-while-retaining-icons-text-for-tab-bar-controller)

[How to add storyboard reference in another storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34578696/how-to-add-storyboard-reference-in-another-storyboard)

Comment: There is no issue of movie tabbar to other storyboard, issue is movie other storyboard to tabbar storyboard or any other viewcontroller of same storyboard